# python: read and split files in to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, file, list, dictionary, split

I'm having troubles with converting file content into list of dictionaries, could you advise?

```
File content:
host1.example.com#192.168.0.1#web server 
host2.example.com#192.168.0.5#dns server
host3.example.com#192.168.0.7#web server 
host4.example.com#192.168.0.9#application server 
host5.example.com#192.168.0.10#database server
```

There are multiple files in side the folder with the same format. At the end I would like to receive list of dictionaries with the following format:

```
[ {'dns': 'host1.example.com', 'ip': '192.168.0.1', 'description': 'web_server'},
{'dns': 'host2.example.com', 'ip': '192.168.0.5', 'description': 'dns server'}, 
{'dns': 'host3.example.com', 'ip': '192.168.0.7', 'description': 'web server'}, 
{'dns': 'host4.example.com', 'ip': '192.168.0.9', 'description': 'application server'},
{'dns': 'host5.example.com', 'ip': '192.168.0.10', 'description': 'database server'} ]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you want to split each line on `#`. Then, you can use `zip` to zip them together with the labels, then convert it to a dictionary.

```
out = []
labels = ['dns', 'ip', 'description']
for line in data:
    out.append(dict(zip(labels, line.split('#'))))
```

That one append line is a bit complex, so to break it down:

```
# makes the list ['host2.example.com', '192.168.0.7', 'web server']
line.split('#')  

# takes the labels list and matches them up:
# [('dns', 'host2.example.com'),
#  ('ip', '192.168.0.7'),
#  ('description', 'web server')]
zip(labels, line.split('#'))  

# takes each tuple and makes the first item the key,
#  and the second item the value
dict(...)
```

Comment: Actually, your answer is what I would do personally, but unfortunately list comps confuse most people. +1 to you as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
rows = []
for line in input_file:
    r = line.split('#')
    rows.append({'dns':r[0],'ip':r[1],'description':r[2]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file is `infile.txt`

```
>>> entries = (line.strip().split("#") for line in open("infile.txt", "r"))
>>> output = [dict(zip(("dns", "ip", "description"), e)) for e in entries]
>>> print output
[{'ip': '192.168.0.1', 'description': 'web server', 'dns': 'host1.example.com'}, {'ip': '192.168.0.5', 'description': 'dns server', 'dns': 'host2.example.com'}, {'ip': '192.168.0.7', 'description': 'web server', 'dns': 'host3.example.com'}, {'ip': '192.168.0.9', 'description': 'application server', 'dns': 'host4.example.com'}, {'ip': '192.168.0.10', 'description': 'database server', 'dns': 'host5.example.com'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> map(lambda x : dict(zip(("dns", "ip", "description"), tuple(x.strip().split('#')))), open('input_file'))
```

Comment: I love `map` as much as the next guy, but there is recently a big push to use list comprehensions, instead. See Shawn Chin's answer.